# What quality of canvas should i use to print?

Tags: print-production, image-quality, canvas

I'm very new at graphic art, actually this is my first canvas so i didn't really check the size and quality of my canvas before starting my drawing. And honestly i would'nt know how, these numbers are all like chinese to me... In the end, i really like it and i would like to print it. But how should i set the canvas to print it on a 32×45 cm (so roughly 12.60×17.72") poster? 
And is there a way to do so without starting my drawing all over again? (Really hope so, took me a hell of a time to do this. Lol)
I think my curent settings are at 830 x 1000px 72dpi.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no quality defined in your post by the way.

Comment: If the file is *artwork*, as in an illustration or painting, not a hard-edged lines and type, you can often get away with up-sampling *illustrations*. It depends a great deal on the art itself, but the up-sampling is far more forgiving in illustrations than it is for photos or type.

Answer (score 0):

For print, you need a higher resolution image.  Your current image is too small for a good quality print at that size. 300ppi is the usual setting for a print.

To work out the size you need, multiply the PPI by the size in inches to work out the dimensions in pixels. For example:

12.6*300 = 3780px, and 17.2*300 = 5316px

Sadly there's nothing you can do to fix it except start again with a larger size document.  Scaling images up (called resampling) degrades image quality significantly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Very helpful. :)

Comment: But keep in mind that not every print requires 300ppi sources. Depending on the materials, print method and usage you might get away with less resolution or even require more. The best you can do to determine your file settings in advance is to check with your printer whtat he requires for the product you want.

Comment: Jade could also try use Illustrator to create trace file and vectorise the artwork and isolate line work and fill - this can be scaled to print clearly - depends on original artwork, maybe post an example for reference

Answer (score 0):

You can try an image enlargening program which resample a low res image file to higher resolution without making it blurry or pixelated. It guesses which borders and edges are better to keep sharp and where are smooth gradients which should stay smooth. I have used them several times when the only available image had far too low pixel dimensions for printing in the wanted size.

Those programs cannot guess missing details, but they keep the image looking sharp. I have tried Smilla (freeware) and ON1 Resizer (commercial) with good results, but there are several others.

Comment: Wow good to know, i'm gonna try that! Thank you for your answer.